# Using exists in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to execute below code and throws me an error "cal_date" doesnt exits.

i have derived a new column "cal_date"

```
select  A.*
from my_table1 A
where exists(select distinct id ,date1 +integer '30' as cal_date
from my_table1
where id=A.id 
and  (date1 = A.date1) 
or (date1 < A.date1 and cal_date<=A.date1));
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff for a distinct customer_id trying to keep observations with in 30 days. We need to remove the observation outside 30 day window

Comment: What 30 day window?  There is a simpler way to write the query; I just don't know what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cant use column alias in where clause. You can simply use this:

```
select  A.*
from my_table1 A
where exists(select distinct id ,date1 +integer '30' as cal_date
from my_table1
where id=A.id 
and  (date1 = A.date1) 
or (date1 < A.date1 and A.date1 >= '30'));
```

Edit: Fixed the quote characters